# Interval for $\alpha$, so that the given line is normal to $xy=4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, euclidean-geometry

Find the interval for $\alpha$ so that $(3-\alpha)x+{\alpha}y+({\alpha}^2-1)=0$ is normal to the curve $xy=4$.

I don't understand why do we need an interval for $\alpha$? The curve is a hyperbola and any straight line can intersect it at maximum $2$ values(that too, is a difficult case). Should the question not ask about discrete values of $\alpha$?

If there is a range involved, just tell me how to go about it...
Thanks!

Comment: The question is asking for the values of alpha for which the line intersects the curve at 90 degrees (i.e. is normal to it) at some point.

Comment: So how do I proceed? I first found out the equation to any normal to this curve (in parametric form) and then compared the coefficients. But that is really tiring. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could test if the line is normal to the hyperbola. The result of the test will depend on $\alpha$, and thus you could then solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: Could anyone give a more subtle hint? I keep inserting the knowns and end up into a biquadratic that I just can't go ahead on.

Answer (score 2):

Consider some point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the curve $xy=4$, where $y_0 = 4/x_0$. The derivative at this point is $-4/x_0^2$.

Therefore, for the line to be normal to this point, it needs to pass through $(x_0, y_0)$, and have a gradient which is the negative reciprocal of that of the curve, i.e. $x_0^2/4$.

Plug this information into the equation for your line, and see which range of values for alpha satisfies these conditions.